# centering an image horizontall and vertically inside a DIV in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, css, image, html

I want to display an ASP.NET image in the middle of a div (both horizontally and vertically), how should I arrange my div and image (image should be runat=server), also I should set max-width and max-height styles for my image, DIV acts as a placeholder, and my image should be inside the DIV, and it should be exactly centered both horizontally and vertically, can you show my the correct HTML and CSS? is there any sample?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

CSS

```
    .placeholder{min-width:200px; min-height:200px;}
    .placeholder img{
    margin: 0px auto; /*centers element horizontally*/
    vertical-align:middle; /*centers element vertically */
    }
```

Your html should like something like:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="placeholder">
       <!-- load image here -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where should I use these styles? these should be set for my ASP.NET image control? what about my div? it doesn't need any CSS?

Comment: Please post your code. This method will not work on floated elements. It is hard to pinpoint what you are working with, without seeing any of your code, the best I can do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

I worked REALLY HARD on finding the solution, hopeful it's 100% helpful :-)

```
<html>
<style>
.placeholder {
    width: 250px;
    min-width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    min-height: 250px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 40%;   
    margin: -100px 0 0 -125px;
}
</style>
<IMG class="placeholder" src="http://www.swoo.co.uk/content/images/icons/stackoverflow.png">
</html>
```

Replace any img you want in place of the URL that equals to the "src".
Note that it works also while zoom in and zoom out in the browser, it stays EXACTLY in the MIDDLE of the page, best code you could find :)